# Live refresh of question/answer scores on Teams doesn't work

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, live-refresh

On a Stack Exchange site, if you are on the question page, you'll see the post scores updating live as people vote on them. On Stack Overflow for Teams, this feature doesn't seem to work, even though other live updates (like the achievements) do work.

Comment: The home page doesn't update with new questions either

Comment: No form of live refresh works on Teams. You don't see notifications of new comments or answers on question pages. (Can you please update this to say Teams instead of Channels?)

Comment: All the live updates on SE/SO happen through the WebSocket, at least all those not initiated by user action. I'm not aware of there being any WebSocket route available for Teams, although I haven't really looked that hard. I must admit that I've more or less assumed the fact that I've never seen any live updates to indicate that they are not available.